# Group By List of object on multiple fields Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, group-by

I will have a list of Employee, which will hold 3 attributes - departmentId, employeeId, employeeGroup.

I want to perform group by on Department Id and employee id. The idea is to send the group name of employee with belonging department. Below can be the 3 possible cases:

**Case#1: Same department, different employee, different group.**

```
["Dept001", 100, "Admin"]
["Dept001", 101, "Contrator"]
```

**Case#2: Same department, same employee, different group**

```
["Dept001", 100, "Admin"]
["Dept001", 100, "Contrator"]
```

**Case#3: Diff department, diff employee, same group.**

```
["Dept001", 100, "Admin"]
["Dept002", 101, "Admin"]
```

I have tried below:

```
Map<String, Set<Employee>> map = new TreeMap<>();

map = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartmentId, 
Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do. Could you give a more elaborative example. What is your input, what should your output be, where exactly is the problem / where do you need help?

Comment: 1. Input is - A list of employee. 2. Output would be employee group name which will be grouped by department id and employee id. 3. I want the way how we can group by multiple fields in above cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by multiple fields is going to require multiple calls to [`Collectors#groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)). Luckily, the second parameter of the overloaded [`Collectors#groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) method is another [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html), so it can simply be invoked twice.

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Set<Employee>>> map = myList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartmentId, 
        Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmployeeId, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Note that the value of the `Map` is another `Map`; the first of which is keyed with the employees' department ID, and the second is keyed with the employees' employee ID.

Comment: This is exactly, what I was expecting and thinking. let me try this approach. Thank you @Jacob

Comment: What you expect in Case#2? @Jacob G.

Comment: Without running the code, I'd expect the result `Map` for Case #2 to be: `{"Dept001"={100=[Employee["Dept001", 100, "Admin"], Employee["Dept001", 100, "Contrator"]]}}`

Comment: This was expected; but this not happening. The output is: {"Dept001": {100: [Employee["Dept001", 100, "Admin"]]}}

Comment: @DeskToDevelop I suspect your `Employee#equals` and `Employee#hashCode` methods were not overridden correctly; are you able to edit your question to include them?

Comment: Thanks. You just saved me. I dont know what I was doing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you just want to do `groupBy` with `EmployeeId` and `DepartmentId` so that afterward you can uniquely identify an employee with this combined property.

You can use `stream` combined with `Tuple`, code will look like this:

`Map<Tuple, List<Emplyee>> map = employees.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(employee-> new Tuple(employee.getEmployeeId(), employee.getDepartmentId())));`

Comment: If you see, the fields which I want to group by is Integer and String. So just doing your solution will not help I guess.

Comment: I guess it will work fine, you can create one of `Tuples` like `Pair` with any `datatype` combined.